# CSS 100% Width Broken

Tags: html, css

I'm developing a PHP/HTML5/CSS3 page and have run into an issue. I somehow had this working perfectly then added some code, made some changes, and broke it.

The concept was that multiple portions of the page would be at 100% width, but with predefined heights. Now however, at width:100% it runs the full width, less 15-20 px (~1%). It has properties CSS stylings such as:

```
html {
width: 100%;
}

body{
background-color:#fbf9ec;
font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
width:100%;
}


#upperContainer{
height: 100px;
width: 875px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
}

#topLogo{
width: 250px;
height:75px;
background-image:url(../images/logo.png)
}

#nav{
background-image:url(../images/nav-bg.png);
height: 32px;
width: 100%;
margin-left:-10px;
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

#featuredContent{
height: 336px;
width: 100%;
margin-left:-12px;
background-image:url(../images/featured-bg.png);
}

#sliderA{
background: #3a7c38;
height: 326px;
width: 873px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 10px 0 0 0;
border:1px #353f35;
border-right-style:solid;
border-left-style:solid;
position: relative;
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I think you'll have to show us some markup code

Comment: No idea without seeing some HTML. Try reducing this to the absolute minimum of HTML and CSS, and someone will probably be able to help.

Comment: I agree with @Vague, some HTML will probably be necessary to debug this. You could add it to [this jsFiddle I created](http://jsfiddle.net/qWS6k/) with your CSS.

Comment: I added HTML to the JSFiddle page at http://jsfiddle.net/3eXBd/.

Comment: Also, I didn't include it initially because I assumed my error was in the CSS. Thanks!

Comment: Even more fixed version here: http://jsfiddle.net/3eXBd/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have negative left margins set. Remove them and see if it lines up.

```
#nav{
    margin-left:-10px;
}

#featuredContent{
    margin-left:-12px;
}
```

Comment: I am aware of that, but when it was working, that was what was keeping it correctly aligned.

Comment: @MasonWinsauer: This answer seems correct to me. When I removed these negative margins in the jsFiddle, that corrected the alignment. There is a negative margin on `#textWrapper` in addition to these two that I also had to remove.

Comment: @MasonWinsauer When I view that link, your body has a computed style of `margin:8px;` so I'd suspect that's throwing everything off. Probably need to address that too.

Comment: @MetalFrog Interesting - I have no doubt that's what's doing it, but what would be causing it?

Comment: @MasonWinsauer Not sure, took a quick look at the css, didn't see anything that should add it. It's in both Dragonfly and Chrome's inspector, so it's not just something funky with Opera. My guess is that it's one of the javascript files, but searching for `body` and `margin` in those files is a nightmare. Try including them one at a time and see which file adds it in.